# Show rule names for Vue CLI warnings from Prettier

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-cli, prettier

The presets I chose for my Vue CLI project have rules that warn me about something in my HTML like this:

```
warning: Replace `·title="Publicly·Visible"·:class="{·inactive:·!member.isPubliclyVisible·}">�</span` with `␍⏎··············title="Publicly·Visible"␍⏎··············:class="{ ·inactive:·!member.isPubliclyVisible·}"␍⏎··············>�</span␍⏎············` (prettier/prettier) at src\views\MemberList.vue:29:18:
  27 |             <span title="Archived" :class="{ inactive: !member.isArchived }">�</span>
  28 |             <span title="Honorary Member" :class="{ inactive: !member.isHonoraryMember }">�</span>
> 29 |             <span title="Publicly Visible" :class="{ inactive: !member.isPubliclyVisible }"> </span>
     |                  ^
  30 |             <span title="Student" :class="{ inactive: !member.isStudent }">�</span>
  31 |           </td>
  32 |         </tr>
```

I don't agree with this rule and want to turn it off. However, it's pretty hard to find out from the message itself which rule this is.

I want to know *how I can configure the Vue CLI and/or eslint to tell me* what the rule is, so that I'm not only set for this specific rule, but also in the future if I want to turn off other rules.

**How can I find out what specific rule is related to a vue-cli based eslint warning?**

My current `.eslintrc.js` file looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "@vue/prettier"],
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off"
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint"
  }
};
```

I get the quoted error when I run `npm serve`, which runs `vue-cli-service serve` in turn.

Comment: I guessed if you install eslint plugin of your IDE, it would prompt you the name of error rule.

Comment: I do have ESLint 1.8.2 installed in vscode. It only seems to work for full `.js` files (e.g. `store.js`), not `.vue` files. Even then, the IDE only shows the suggested fix with "eslint(prettier/prettier)" as additional explanation. - But if there's a way to get what I want in VSCode that would be an acceptable to me personally (though others might still want a CLI solution).

Comment: I know this is an old question but I have the same issue and wondered if you figured out a solution? I have all the relevant plugins but vscode doesn't want to show me the rule name that's being broken.

Comment: Alas, at the time I never found out and in the mean time I've been working mostly in React and Svelte codebases. It's interesting no one from the community ever added an answer in all those years...

Answer (score 0):

So far, the answer to whether Prettier will list the rules impacting a code block is a "no," per the Prettier people themselves: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6069.

To summarize the link's content, someone submitted a now-closed GitHub issue asking for a flag that outputs the Prettier rules applied to a code block. Sadly, the Prettier people did not understand the need. For example, they suggest using `prettylint`, yet `prettylint` only says what lines it will change, not why.

Given the 1K+ other issues associated with the Prettier repo, this is one of many needs Prettier cannot meet.